# Using bin labels with source data frame

Tags: r, bin

Let's say we have a dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(700)

clientID <- round(runif(200,min=2000, max=3000),0)
orders <- round(runif(200,min=1, max=50),0)    

df <- data.frame(cbind(clientID,orders))
```

And I'm using a function that bins it for me and aggregates to whatever I want it to be variables (counts, sums, etc). So I have this:

```
         Count
(-Inf,5]    23
(5,9.8]     17
(9.8,15]    22
(15,19]     19
(19,24]     21
(24,31.4]   18
(31.4,35]   24
(35,38.2]   16
(38.2,44]   21
(44, Inf]   19
Missing      0
TOTAL      200
```

How to use these row labels that I've got after binning df$orders by quartiles, to have a new variable with these labels but for source dataframe? So instead of df$orders (or as a new variable) I will have these labels, along with 'missing' label. That the dataframe I used for binning will have these labels as a new column.

And of course the case is to automate it, not to rewrite it by hand :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the output of `dput(summary data)`. Since your rownames are unusual, it'd be best to work with them directly rather than guessing their format/class.

Comment: row.names = c("(-Inf,5]", 
"(5,9.8]", "(9.8,15]", "(15,19]", "(19,24]", "(24,31.4]", "(31.4,35]", 
"(35,38.2]", "(38.2,44]", "(44, Inf]", "Missing", "TOTAL"), class = "data.frame") - this is what you ment?

Comment: a side note, `data.frame(cbind(...))` makes no sense. it's either `data.frame(...)` (to get a data frame) or `cbind(...)` (to get a matrix). A combination will give you a data frame after converting it to a matrix.  for example, `data.frame(cbind(1:5,2:6, LETTERS[1:5]))` has 3 factor columns instead of 2 numeric and 1 character/factor.